# Runtime error when trying to add item to list property in a class in C#

Tags: c#, list, enums, properties, class-properties

I have a class with a property that is a List of `enum` values to be filled in runtime (I'm using a List instead of an array because I don't know beforehand how many items there will be).

I declared the property like this:

```
public class Entity 
{
    // ...
    public List<FooEnum> FooList { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

where `FooEnum` has the following structure:

```
public enum FooEnum
{

    [Description( "Foo: " )]
    Foo = 1,

    [Description( "Boo: " )]
    Boo = 3,

    [Description( "Loo: " )]
    Loo,

    //...
}
```

To add items to the list I added the following method to the Entity class:

```
public void SetFoos( string packet )
{
    VectorSize = short.Parse( ExtractValue( packet, "ListSize: " ) );

    for( int i = 0, start = packetIndexOf( "ListSize" ); i < VectorSize; i++ )
    {
        string reducedPacket = packet.Substring( start );
        string currentFoo = ExtractValue( packet, "--------------\r\n" );

        foreach( FooEnum foo in FooEnum.GetValues( typeof( FooEnum ) ) )
        {
            if( foo.Description().StartsWith( currentFoo ) ) { FooList.Add(foo); break; }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't implemented the start update logic yet because I wanted to test an example where VectorSize was 1, but when running the program I got a runtime error:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference undefined for object instance

I tried to declare the list as `public List<FooEnum> FooList = new List<FooEnum>();`, but immediately I got a warning telling me that

> Field "Entity.FooList" is never atributted and will always have a default null value

so I went back to using a getter and a setter.

I tried to find some examples of List properties in C# and based on them I tried changing my declaration to

```
public class Entity 
{
    // ...
    private List<FooEnum> fooList;
    public List<FooEnum> FooList 
    {
        get { return fooList; } 
        set { fooList = value; } 
    }
    // ... 
}
```

but I got the same runtime error.

What am I missing? Is it not possible to use a list of Enums as a class property?

Comment: If `FooEnum` is really an `enum` type, this `foo.Description()` will not compile, of you don't have an extension method for this type. Please, share `FooEnum` and `Description()` method

Comment: Is `SetFoos` defined in `Entity` class?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have edited my question to include the Enum structure, but I can't share the description method as it is part of an external library with various Enum utils. I can tell you it takes an Enum value and returns a string containing its description, if it has one.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, the method is inside the Entity class, I've edited the question to make that clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `Entity` class and initialize the `FooList` or `foolist` like below

```
public class Entity 
{
    public List<FooEnum> FooList { get; set; }

    // ctor 
    public Entity()
    {
        FooList = new List<FooEnum>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your fooList before adding foo, like below line:

```
    fooList = new List<FooEnum>();
```